Adding a multidimensional array to an option in Wordpress but it overwrites instead of adding
I'm trying to add a new function to a plugin for that I want to save the preferences on the options of WordPress to use on the front later, I made it update but it does only on 1 array instead of adding the array after the last 1, this is the code:


public
function hidden_callback() {
  // getting data
  $existing_data = get_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options', array());

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options'])) {
    $input = $_POST['dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options'];

    if (isset($input['model']) && isset($input['start_year']) && isset($input['end_year']) && isset($input['term']) && isset($input['value'])) {
      // new array using form data
      $new_entry = array(
        'model' => sanitize_text_field($input['model']),
        'start_year' => absint($input['start_year']),
        'end_year' => absint($input['end_year']),
        'term' => absint($input['term']),
        'value' => floatval($input['value']),
        'iscpo' => isset($input['iscpo']) ? filter_var($input['iscpo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) : false,
      );

      // Check if $existing_data is an array, if not, initialize it
      if (!is_array($existing_data)) {
        $existing_data = array();
      }

      // Add the new object to the existing array
      $existing_data[] = $new_entry;

      // Update the option with the updated array
      update_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options', $existing_data);
    }
  }
}



if I do a dd of the data stored I get:


array:6 [▼
  "model" => "prueba test 2"
  "start_year" => "2000"
  "end_year" => "2002"
  "term" => "20"
  "value" => "2"
  "iscpo" => "on"
]



after adding more data it overwrite the existing one instead of adding after, my desired output would be:


[
    [
        model=>'model1',
        start_year=>1000,
        end_year=>1001,
        term=>10,
        value=>1,
        iscpo=>true,
    ],
    [
        model=>'model2',
        start_year=>2000,
        end_year=>2001,
        term=>20,
        value=>2,
        iscpo=>false,
    ],
]



here is my function for displaying later:


public
function display_saved_data() {
  // Asegurarse de que los datos se guardan correctamente
  $saved_data = get_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options');
  if (!empty($saved_data)) {
    dd($saved_data);
    echo '<h2>Saved Data:</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>';
    echo 'Model: '.esc_html($saved_data['model']).
    ', ';
    echo 'Start Year: '.esc_html($saved_data['start_year']).
    ', ';
    echo 'End Year: '.esc_html($saved_data['end_year']).
    ', ';
    echo 'Term: '.esc_html($saved_data['term']).
    ', ';
    echo 'Value: '.esc_html($saved_data['value']).
    ', ';
    echo 'Is CPO: '.($saved_data['iscpo'] == 'on' ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}



new note: I added some things but it doesn't save the data of the forms:


public function sanitize_fi_c($input) {
    $new_data = array(
            'model' => sanitize_text_field($input['model']),
            'start_year' => absint($input['start_year']),
            'end_year' => absint($input['end_year']),
            'term' => absint($input['term']),
            'value' => floatval($input['value']),
            'iscpo' => isset($input['iscpo']) ? filter_var($input['iscpo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) : false,
    );

    $options = get_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options');
    if (!is_array($options)) {
            $options = array();
    }
    $options[] = $new_data;

    return $options;
}





public function hidden_callback() {
    if (isset($_POST['form_submitted']) && $_POST['form_submitted'] === 'yes') {
        // Recolectar y procesar los datos
        $input = array(
            'model' => $_POST['model'],
            'start_year' => $_POST['start_year'],
            'end_year' => $_POST['end_year'],
            'term' => $_POST['term'],
            'value' => $_POST['value'],
            'iscpo' => isset($_POST['iscpo']) ? $_POST['iscpo'] : false,
        );

        // Usar la función de sanitización
        $sanitized_data = $this->sanitize_fi_c($input);

        // Guardar los datos sanitizados
        $existing_data = get_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options', array());
        $existing_data[] = $sanitized_data;
        update_option('dealer-settings-used-finance-custom-options', $existing_data);

        // Redireccionar para evitar el reenvío del formulario
        wp_redirect(admin_url('options-general.php?page=used-finance-custom'));
        exit;
    }
}



now I get the desired output with the keys, but the values are empty:


array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "model" => ""
    "start_year" => 0
    "end_year" => 0
    "term" => 0
    "value" => 0.0
    "iscpo" => false
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "model" => ""
    "start_year" => 0
    "end_year" => 0
    "term" => 0
    "value" => 0.0
    "iscpo" => false
  ]
]




You are switching from a "one-dimensional" to a two-dimensional array here willy-nilly, that can hardly work. Your stored data should be two-dim to begin with. (I'm guessing what was already stored, is based on older code? Because your current code should always create a two-dimensional array, as far as I can tell.)

that is the case, but this option is a new addition to the old code, but I have seen on stack overflow that I can get an array of arrays( two-dimensional array ) using this: $array = array();
$array[] = array(0, 1, 2);
$array[] = array(3, 4, 5);

So you'll have to check first, if your data is still in the "old" format, and transfer it into the new format, before you add any further items to it. if(isset($existing_data['model'])) { $existing_data[] = $existing_data; }

since is a new option I can erase it without problem using console commands I tried using brute force and inserting:$existing_data = array($new_entry, $new_entry); on an empty option, it still only saves 1
